# Spark: Scala parse json files with jsonschema to DF

Tags: scala, apache-spark, jsonschema

Scala version - 2.12.15 | Spark version - 3.4.1

Trying to parse json files that align to a jsonschema into a dataframe.

Example schemajson -

```
val schemaDefinition = """{"$id": "myclass.schema.json","title": "MyClass","type": "object","properties": {"day": {"type": "string","format": "date"},"timestamp": {"type": "string","format": "date-time"},"method": {"type": "string"},"status": {"type": "integer"}}}"""
```

`DataType.fromJson` and similar alternatives I found thus far expect a simple json schema that isn't [json-schema](https://json-schema.org/) compliant.

Is there a json-schema mapper into StructType?
Only alternative I found is writing a mapper myself that maps the different json-schema types and formats into relevant `org.apache.spark.sql.types` types.

After I have proper schema set up, I would do this:

```
 val jsonDF = spark.read.schema(schema).json(paths: _*)
```

Which works fine with a scala case class, but can't make it work with a json-schema definition